# Where is my mistake in calculating the Fresnel integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, improper-integrals, complex-integration

I want to prove the equation:

$$
\int_0^\infty \sin x^2dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt\frac{\pi}2{}
$$
This was my calculating process:
$$
||e^{iz^2}||=||e^{iR^2e^{i2\theta}}||=e^{-R^2\sin 2\theta}
$$
Using the Jordan Inequality
$$
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-Rsin\theta}d\theta\le \frac{\pi}{2R}(R>0)
$$
I got
$$
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}e^{-R^2\sin 2\theta}d\theta \le \frac{\pi}{4R^2}
$$
Note that the symmetry in $\sin x$

I got
$$
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-R^2\sin 2\theta}d\theta \le \frac{\pi}{2R^2}
$$
Using the Cauchy-gursat theroem,I had
$$
\int_0^Re^{ix^2}dx+\int_{C_R}e^{iz^2}dz+\int_R^0e^{-iy^2}dy=0
$$

The shape of the integral path was like this

[image]

Then
$$
|\int_{C_R}e^{iz^2}dz| \le \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|e^{-R^2\sin 2\theta}Rie^{i\theta}|d\theta\le \frac{\pi}{2R}
$$
When $R \rightarrow \infty$，I got
$$
\int_{C_R}e^{iz^2}dz=0
$$
Then
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{ix^2}dx+\int_\infty^0e^{-iy^2}dy=0
$$
Then
$$
\int_0^\infty(\cos x^2+i\sin x^2) dx-\int_0^\infty(\cos y^2-i\sin y^2)dy=0
$$
Then
$$
2\int_0^\infty i\sin x^2 dx=0
$$
So
$$
\int_0^\infty \sin x^2dx=0
$$
What's wrong with that?Where was my mistake?

I would appreciate it if you could help me.Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain how you went from (what you call) the Jordan inequality to $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}e^{-R^2\sin 2\theta}d\theta \le \frac{\pi}{4R^2}$?

Comment: there are a few typos along the way - $z^2 = R^2\mathrm{e}^{2i\theta} \neq R^2\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}$. 

@fundamentalform - I think he used the bound $\sin \theta \leq \theta$ then integrated.

Comment: @Chinny84 Hmmn, I still don't see why the exponent contains $\sin 2 \theta$; I'm reading between the lines and assuming it is arrived at via the observation that $$|e^{-iR^2e^{2i\theta}}| = e^{-R^2 \sin{2\theta}} $$?

Comment: yeah I believe so. Though not looked at this in detail - but there are exponents that are a little off through out.

Comment: @fundamentalform  I'm sorry.I made some typos .But it doesn't change the result.So could you check it again and find something wrong else?Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is the missing imaginary unit in this equation:
$$
\int_0^Re^{ix^2}dx+\int_{C_R}e^{iz^2}dz+\color{red}i\int_R^0e^{-iy^2}dy=0.
$$
This amounts to the equation:
$$
\int_0^\infty\cos(x^2)+i\sin(x^2)dx=\int_0^\infty\sin(y^2)+i\cos(y^2)dy
$$
or
$$
\int_0^\infty\cos(x^2)dx=\int_0^\infty\sin(x^2)dx,
$$
which is though correct but does not help to evaluate the expression.

To avoid this stop the circle path at $\theta=\frac\pi4$, return to $0$ along the line $\theta=\frac\pi4$, and use the well-known result $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt\frac\pi2$.